# Gunicorn failed to find application when run from a shell file but succeeds when run from cli directly

Tags: python, bash, gunicorn

I am trying to run a gunicorn enclosing a python app but it keeps giving me `failed to find application` error.
Here is the whole trace:

```
[2018-03-06 22:17:39 +0000] [13278] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-03-06 22:17:39 +0000] [13278] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:7007 (13278)
[2018-03-06 22:17:39 +0000] [13278] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2018-03-06 22:17:39 +0000] [13281] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13281
[2018-03-06 22:17:39 +0000] [13285] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13285
[2018-03-06 22:17:39 +0000] [13286] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13286
[2018-03-06 22:17:39 +0000] [13290] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13290
Failed to find application: 'production.server'
[2018-03-06 22:17:42 +0000] [13281] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13281)
Failed to find application: 'production.server'
Failed to find application: 'production.server'
[2018-03-06 22:17:42 +0000] [13285] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13285)
[2018-03-06 22:17:42 +0000] [13290] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13290)
Failed to find application: 'production.server'
[2018-03-06 22:17:42 +0000] [13286] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13286)
[2018-03-06 22:17:42 +0000] [13278] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-03-06 22:17:42 +0000] [13278] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

And my file tree shows that `production/server.py` does exist. I am running the bash command:

```
gunicorn \
-b 0.0.0.0:${port} \
-k gthread \
-w ${proc_count} \
--threads ${thread_count} \
-t 300 \
'production.server:create_app(ensemble)'
```

when I am rooted at the directory containing `production` sub-directory. 
When I run the `Gunicorn` command from bash directly:

```
gunicorn production.server:create_app -b 0.0.0.0:7007
```

it works just fine! 
How can I fix this?

Comment: The bash command seems to be using `create_app(ensemble)` whereas on the command line you are just using `create_app`. What is `ensemble` being passed? Will the bash command work if you don't specify `(ensemble)`?